# Bcc emails still visible using Civicrm (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, email

Email addresses sent using Bcc are visible to the recipients of the emails.

Emails sent using the Bcc field of Thunderbird (actually, Cco in Spanish) work correctly and the standard "undisclosed-recipients" message appears. However, when I receive an email from admins using the Civicrm Bcc functionality, all email addresses that are in the Bcc field are visible in a new "Bcc" field in Thunderbird.

The emails are sent and arrive correctly (all of them, i.e. the individual ones, the ones sent in public copy and the ones sent using blind copy or Bcc), but the latter should not show the email addresses at all to the recipients.

Could it be an error caused by the fact that "Bcc" does not exist in Spanish but "Cco" is used in Spanish?

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post an example of the email headers (with the actual addresses redacted)?

Comment: my recollection is the B (blind) of BCC has not been 'blind' for a long time

Comment: Here you'll find the email headers: https://pastebin.com/ppjsEcf5